# Enable my location icon Googlemap v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have loaded google map it's working perfectly. but how to add this feature.See my pic for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This nice line of code should do the trick:

```
GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

If you want, you could also override what that button does using this:

```
GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(*your custom listener goes here*)
```

**But**, that button will be useless unless you've got `LocationService` enabled. So make sure you check that too. (I've learned it the hard way.)

Answer (score 2):

just write these lines of code:

```
private void myLocationButton() {

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

And if you want to enable Location Service when user clicks this button you can use this:

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    boolean enabledGPS = service
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    boolean enabledWiFi = service
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (!enabledGPS) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (!enabledWiFi) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Network signal not found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

That icon will see automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method.And button will appear.

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```