# How to addMarker directly on GoogleMap after click button setMyLocationEnabled?

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a code.
In this code, when i click a map, there will be  a marker on clicked point.

**This is my Code**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oh, no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                String lat = String.valueOf(point.latitude);
                String lng = String.valueOf(point.longitude);
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("ok");
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Question :** 
What i want is that when i click SetMylocationEnable button, there also added a new marker. And because i want marker is only one in whole map, another marker that has been in the map before is to be removed. How can i do it? Would you teach me?

You can see what button i saying is, in picture. (picture is from : [Enable my location icon Googlemap v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010991/enable-my-location-icon-googlemap-v2))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Location location = getLocation();
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("ok");
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
        return true;
    }
});

private Location getLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
            .getBestProvider(criteria, false));

}
```

Comment: @Cabezas  getMyLocation() is deprecated,Can u updated the answer?

Answer (score 1):

keep a reference to the marker, if the reference is null then create the marker as you have done, if it is not, then edit the marker and change its location